# Ansible file check for multiple servers and files

Tags: windows, ansible

I have a playbook which has three tasks that checks if a file exists, check the date modified is same and the checksum is same. It works fine for a server with one filename, its date and its checksum

```
Vars are serverA, file_name, time, chks1
```

But I have many servers and different files. How can I achieve this?

```
serverA,file1, dat1, chks1
serverA, file2, dat2, chks2
serverB, file3, dat3, chks3 etc…
```

Part of playbook:

```
---
- name: Check if file exists
  win_stat:
   path: "{{file_name}}"
  register: file

- name: Status 
  assert:
   that: file.stat.exists
   fail_msg: "Check failed"
   success_msg: "Check PASSED"
- name: Status modification
  assert:
   that: file.stat.lastwritetime|int  == time|int
   fail_msg: "Check failed"
   success_msg: "Check PASSED"
```

Comment: HI, pls use host_vars for file_name, time, chks1 for particular servers

Answer (score 2):

## Solution 1: declare files in your inventory

If this is somewhat static, you can put this info in your [inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html) variables. Easiest way is in a `host_vars/<inventory_hostname>.yml` files for each host:

```
check_files:
  - name: file1
    time: date1
    checksum: chcks1
  - name: file2
    time: date2
    checksum: chks2
```

Just create a file for each server in your inventory with the corresponding declaration.

Then your tasks would simply look like this (adapted from your examples, not tested).

```
- name: Check if file exists
  win_stat:
    path: "{{ item.name }}"
  register: files
  loop: "{{ check_files }}"

- name: Status 
  assert:
    that: item.stat.exists
    fail_msg: "Check failed"
    success_msg: "Check PASSED"
  loop: "{{ files.results }}"

- name: Status modification
  assert:
    that: item.stat.lastwritetime | int  == item.item.time | int
    fail_msg: "Check failed"
    success_msg: "Check PASSED"
  loop: "{{ files.results }}"
```

## Solution 2: declaration outside of inventory.

If your really want/need to keep those file declarations outside of your inventory and declare them at playbook/play level, you could create a data structure that still references the inventory name of the server, something like:

```
check_files:
  host1:
    - name: file1
      time: date1
      checksum: chks1
    - name: file2
      time: date2
      checksum: chks2
  host2:
    - name: filex
      time: timex
      checksum: chks
```

In this case, the previous example still works. You just have slightly change the loop element in the first task:

```
- name: Check if file exists
  win_stat:
    path: "{{ item.name }}"
  register: files
  loop: "{{ check_files[inventory_hostname] }}"
```

## Notes

- I kept the `checksum` in your data structure because you mentioned it, although it is not used at the moment in any of your sample tasks. You can use it the same way as `time` in the above examples.
- The notation `item.item.time` is not a typing mistake. The loop is over `results` of the previous `win_stat` module run. So `item` references one of the currently looped results, while `item.item` references the item that was actually used when running that task (i.e. an actual file in your variables declaration)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer would be do a code duplication and write this check as many times as you need. If you want to be a smart cookie and try to DRY, you may want to start to use host_vars (to keep there differences between servers), or, if you need this for few files for one server, to use `import_tasks` module with different values for 'vars' section for the task.